# problems connecting sqlite database built using php5

Tags: php, sqlite

I have used php5 to create a sqlite database. The database works fine when accessing its data using php.

However when I try and connect to the same sqlite file using firefox sqlite manager, I get the following error....

> SQLiteManager: Error in opening file jTest.sqlite - either the file is
>   encrypted or corrupt Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED Exception
>   Message: Component returned failure code: 0x8052000b
>   (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [mozIStorageService.openUnsharedDatabase]

My question:
Can you use php to create sqlite databases and have them work in other applications?

regards J